# How to get a value from a JSON object in C#

Tags: c#, json

How can I get a value from a JSON Object? I don't know if I need to convert it into a class or I can directly get it from the text file which is .json text. This is the JSON file that I have created:

```
{
  "801": {
    "Name": "Tarlac",
    "Lanes": {
      "2": {
        "Ip": "172.23.101.21"
      },
      "4": {
        "Ip": "172.23.101.41"
      },
      "6": {
        "Ip": "172.23.101.61"
      },
      "8": {
        "Ip": "172.23.101.81"
      },
      "9": {
        "Ip": "172.23.101.91"
      },
      "11": {
        "Ip": "172.23.101.111"
      }
    }
  },
  "803": {
    "Name": "Victoria",
    "Lanes": {
      "3": {
        "Ip": "172.23.103.31"
      },
      "6": {
        "Ip": "172.23.103.61"
      }
    }
  },
  "805": {
    "Name": "Pura",
    "Lanes": {
      "4": {
        "Ip": "172.23.105.41"
      },
      "6": {
        "Ip": "172.23.105.61"
      },
      "9": {
        "Ip": "172.23.105.91"
      },
      "7": {
        "Ip": "172.23.105.71"
      }
    }
  },
  "807": {
    "Name": "Ramos",
    "Lanes": {
      "3": {
        "Ip": "172.23.107.31"
      },
      "5": {
        "Ip": "172.23.107.51"
      }
    }
  },
  "809": {
    "Name": "Anao",
    "Lanes": {
      "3": {
        "Ip": "172.23.109.31"
      },
      "5": {
        "Ip": "172.23.109.51"
      }
    }
  },
  "811": {
    "Name": "Carmen",
    "Lanes": {
      "2": {
        "Ip": "172.23.111.21"
      },
      "4": {
        "Ip": "172.23.111.41"
      },
      "6": {
        "Ip": "172.23.111.61"
      }
    }
  },
  "813": {
    "Name": "Urdaneta",
    "Lanes": {
      "4": {
        "Ip": "172.23.113.41"
      },
      "6": {
        "Ip": "172.23.113.61"
      },
      "8": {
        "Ip": "172.23.113.81"
      },
      "9": {
        "Ip": "172.23.113.91"
      }
    }
  },
  "815": {
    "Name": "Binalonan",
    "Lanes": {
      "3": {
        "Ip": "172.23.115.31"
      },
      "5": {
        "Ip": "172.23.115.51"
      }
    }
  },
  "817": {
    "Name": "Pozorrubio",
    "Lanes": {
      "3": {
        "Ip": "172.23.117.31"
      },
      "4": {
        "Ip": "172.23.117.41"
      },
      "6": {
        "Ip": "172.23.117.61"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

I tried creating a class so it can hold all of my JSON values and "maybe" be able to search through it, like so:

```
using System.Collections.Generic;

namespace TagReporting.Models
{
    class Plaza
    {
        public string Code { get; set; }
        public PlazaInfo PlazaInfo { get; set; }
    }

    class PlazaInfo
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public List<Lane> Lanes { get; set; }
    }

    class Lane
    {
        public string Code { get; set; }
        public string IpAddress { get; set; }
    }
}
```

And try to deserialize it using a code like this:

```
private void GetPlazaInformation()
{
    using (var streamReader = new StreamReader(Path.Combine(Path.GetDirectoryName(Assembly.GetEntryAssembly()?.Location) ?? throw new InvalidOperationException(), "Data/plaza.json")))
    {
        var json = streamReader.ReadToEnd();
        var plaza = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Plaza>(json);
    }
}
```

Placing a breakpoint, all I get is a null value like this:

> code: null, PlazaInfo: null

I just want to search for a value in my JSON file. Example:

Get the Ip of "813" Lane "6" which is "172.23.113.61"

Comment: If you just want to search, you don't need to deserialize the JSON. Just treat it as text

Comment: Looks more like a `Dictionary<string, PlazaInfo>()` to me, since the `Code` property doesn't exist in the JSON (not named as a property).

Comment: @ThomasWeller Can you give me a sample please.

Comment: @ThomasWeller THANK YOU for giving me that advice. I was able to get it!

Comment: FYI: https://dailydotnettips.com/did-you-know-you-can-automatically-create-classes-from-json-or-xml-in-visual-studio/  If you are having problems with your model

Comment: This JSON is not properly formed to be easily parsed, It is not represent a list

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like this ?
[Snippet on Fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/EvREQF)

```
using System;
using Newtonsoft.Json.Linq;

public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        String Json = "{'801': {'Name': 'Tarlac','Lanes': {'2': {'Ip': '172.23.101.21'},'4': {'Ip': '172.23.101.41'},'6': {'Ip': '172.23.101.61'},'8': {'Ip': '172.23.101.81'},'9': {'Ip': '172.23.101.91'},'11': {'Ip': '172.23.101.111'}}},'803': {'Name': 'Victoria','Lanes': {'3': {'Ip': '172.23.103.31'},'6': {'Ip': '172.23.103.61'}}},'805': {'Name': 'Pura','Lanes': {'4': {'Ip': '172.23.105.41'},'6': {'Ip': '172.23.105.61'},'9': {'Ip': '172.23.105.91'},'7': {'Ip': '172.23.105.71'}}},'807': {'Name': 'Ramos','Lanes': {'3': {'Ip': '172.23.107.31'},'5': {'Ip': '172.23.107.51'}}},'809': {'Name': 'Anao','Lanes': {'3': {'Ip': '172.23.109.31'},'5': {'Ip': '172.23.109.51'}}},'811': {'Name': 'Carmen','Lanes': {'2': {'Ip': '172.23.111.21'},'4': {'Ip': '172.23.111.41'},'6': {'Ip': '172.23.111.61'}}},'813': {'Name': 'Urdaneta','Lanes': {'4': {'Ip': '172.23.113.41'},'6': {'Ip': '172.23.113.61'},'8': {'Ip': '172.23.113.81'},'9': {'Ip': '172.23.113.91'}}},'815': {'Name': 'Binalonan','Lanes': {'3': {'Ip': '172.23.115.31'},'5': {'Ip': '172.23.115.51'}}},'817': {'Name': 'Pozorrubio','Lanes': {'3': {'Ip': '172.23.117.31'},'4': {'Ip': '172.23.117.41'},'6': {'Ip': '172.23.117.61'}}}}".Replace('\'','"');
        JObject JsonDe = JObject.Parse(Json);
        Console.WriteLine(JsonDe["813"]["Lanes"]["6"]);
    }
}
```